# I Want create bootstrap grid leaving certain amount of space from left side

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I Want create bootstrap grid leaving certain amount of space from left side like in screen shot i want create a bootstrap grid (like Container-fluid > row > column..etc) in the area with green border leaving the space of 70px from left for my sidebar (red border area) need help in the same.

thank you in advance

following is link for the image will give more clarity

link updated

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2p5k1s7yw310ty/Screen%20shot_boot.png?dl=0

Comment: Post the image URL which does not require permissions to see.

Comment: use `padding` for leaving space

Comment: Use margin or padding for space,
Your link is not public. First make it public for more help.

Comment: link is updated for image

Comment: In fact, when you use Bootstrap Twitter 3 grid system, the grid is set relative to the width of his `container` or `container-fluid` parent. Since you have an element wrapping the "white" space where you need your grid to be created, you can use grid system like usual in this particular element (at best, a `<div>`). You should provide a few HTML code in order to point out the right div to update.

Comment: if i give my container-fluid a parent container an give it margin-left will it work?

Answer (score 1):

Set your code in in between div :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"> (red border area)</div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10"> (green border area)</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: if i give my container-fluid a parent container an give it margin-left will it work?